# Any way to restrict image size on upload?

Tags: image, validation, crop

I have some fields where multiple images are uploaded. These images need to be created manually to ensure they're cropped correctly, and I want to ensure that each field only accepts an image cropped to exact dimensions. I don't want to crop the images programatically.

For example, field 1 accepts an image cropped exactly to 1000px by 300px, field 2 accepts 700px by 250px, and so on.

Wondering if there's any way to have this kind of validation in Expression Engine, either with a plugin or core functionality?

Answer (score 1):

In order for ExpressionEngine to know anything at all about the images they would first need to be uploaded.

Perhaps something like this? http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/

You'd need to look for something that worked on the client side via Flash or Javascript which could test the file before the upload process starts.

Comment: If someone could implement that front end upload handling to place images into a matrix field, I would be eternally grateful!
Theres not a lot of options when it comes to front end image handling.

Answer (score 1):

From what i understand from your question you need Ansel: https://buzzingpixel.com/software/ansel-ee

We had some issues getting this to work with Zurb Foundation though. We implemented a solution with the help of https://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropperjs/

Comment: Wow, that looks like pretty great software. Sure beats out-of-the-box EE image manipulations.